# MavenProject setValue not change pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I have a problem with MavenProject class. I make a maven plugin and i am using this class to get pom properties like groupId and version. Everytime when i use my plugin to set something- e.g:

```
public class versionGoal extends AbstractMojo {

/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project}"
 */
private MavenProject mavenProject;

/**
 * @throws org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
 */
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
{
    this.mavenProject.setVersion("9.0.0");
}
```

}

after execution e.g in test phase nothing change. But if i try add in code line: mavenProject.getVersion() after line this.mavenProject.setVersion("9.0.0") return me "9.0.0", but pom.xml wouldn't be changed.

Probably it's some stupid mistake, i know:) And i know that exist version-maven-plugin, but i don't want to use it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: First why not using versions-maven-plugin instead what would you like to make different and why? Of course you can't simply change the pom, cause within the runtime you can only access the loaded values of your pom and not the files on the hard drive. Furthermore why are you using old style XDoclect style instead of [Java 1.5 Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are just changing in memory data:

You have to use [`ModelWriter`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/io/ModelWriter.html?is-external=true) to persist changes or additions.

*NOTE: this is probably a really bad practice if you go changing things like `version` unless you are very specific about the behavior as a side effect*

Writes the supplied model to the specified file.

```
void    write(File output, Map<String,Object> options, Model model)
```

Writes the supplied model to the specified byte stream.

```
void    write(OutputStream output, Map<String,Object> options, Model model)
```

Writes the supplied model to the specified character writer.

```
void    write(Writer output, Map<String,Object> options, Model model)
```

*This is easily found in the JavaDoc*

Comment: After you have used the above all your comments and many other things are gone. versions-maven-plugin uses special things to hold such informations etc.

Comment: read the JavaDoc, there are more things you need to do, they are explained there very well, I am not going to duplicate that effort.